# Google Charts (GeoChart) - Europe region doesn't display correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I'm struggling to find out why geochart map cuts top of the map when using the Europe region.

For example Finland does not show up completely.

Has anyone ever encountered such problem?

Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'ColorIndex'],
          ['fi', 2],
          ['ee', 1],
          ['gb', 2],
          ['at', 2],
          ['dk', 2],
          ['es', 2]
        ]);
var opts = {
    region: '150',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    resolution: 'countries',
    width: 480,
    height: 320,
    enableRegionInteractivity: true,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip : { trigger : 'none' },
    colorAxis: {
      values: [1, 2, 3],
      colors: ['#050b55', '#003399', '#eb5f0f']
    }
};

var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);
            geochart.draw(data, opts);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="visualization" style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
```